# Combining sequential jQuery selectors into a single function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

**BIG EDIT: Updated the code sections, but the question remains the same.**

I've got perhaps a unique jQuery issue that I could use some help on.

I've got a function (that works perfectly) that looks like this...

```
var openslide1 = function() { 
      $("#slide1").animate({
        left: "+=250px",
      }, 400, function() {
        // Animation complete.
      });
      $(this).unbind('click', openslide1); \\ to prevent from pushing slide over too many times
};

$("#openslide1").click(openslide1);
```

My issue is there could be a potentially unlimited number of slides, and therefore "openslides". Each "openslide" selector corresponds with its own unique slide. (e.g. #openslide2 would open #slide2 and unbind #openslide2...so on and so forth).

So how do I combine these into a single variable and function?

And as a side note...I'm also going to want to "re-bind" the #openslide on the click of another event. Currently, I'm able to do them one at a time through this....

```
$("#closeslide1").click(function() {
    $("#slide1").animate({
        left: "-=250px",
      }, 500, function() {
        // Animation complete.
      }); 
    $('#openslide1').click(openslide1); \\ rebinds openslide1
});
```

But once this becomes a combined function, I'm assuming "openslide1" will no longer be the variable for the function. So how would I rebind that click event when #closeslide is clicked. (And obviously I'm going to use the first part of this question to apply to the closeslide variables as well.)

```
<div class="section">
<a class="edit-btn" id="openslide1" href="#null">edit</a>
<a class="edit-btn" id="openslide2" href="#null">edit</a>
<a class="edit-btn" id="openslide3" href="#null">edit</a>
<a class="edit-btn" id="openslide4" href="#null">edit</a>
</div>
<div class="slide" id="slide1">
<h1>Edit Row</h1>
<p>Prototyping data below, may not reflect link clicked.</p>
<a href="#null" id="submitslide1" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</a> <a id="closeslide1" class="btn btn-danger" style="color:#fff" href="#null">Cancel</a>
</div>
<div class="slide" id="slide2">
<h1>Edit Row</h1>
<p>Prototyping data below, may not reflect link clicked.</p>
<a href="#null" id="submitslide2" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</a> <a id="closeslide2" class="btn btn-danger" style="color:#fff" href="#null">Cancel</a>
</div>
<div class="slide" id="slide3">
<h1>Edit Row</h1>
<p>Prototyping data below, may not reflect link clicked.</p>
<a href="#null" id="submitslide3" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</a> <a id="closeslide3" class="btn btn-danger" style="color:#fff" href="#null">Cancel</a>
</div>
<div class="slide" id="slide4">
<h1>Edit Row</h1>
<p>Prototyping data below, may not reflect link clicked.</p>
<a href="#null" id="submitslide4" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</a> <a id="closeslide4" class="btn btn-danger" style="color:#fff" href="#null">Cancel</a>
</div>
```

PLEASE HELP!

Thanks!

Comment: I'm having trouble visualizing what you're trying to do. Perhaps some pictures would help?

Comment: What he has currently works, but he doesn't want to have x functions where x is the number of slides he has.

Comment: I can't add pictures do to this being a work project. Essentially, when someone clicks on a link with a class of "openslide1", this triggers the body and a slide with a class "slide1" to shift to the right. It also unbinds the "openslide1" link so it won't shift the page to the right continually. My problem is that there could be dozens of slides and subsequent "openslide" links. How do I create a function that will always connect the "openslide" link to it's unique slide?

Comment: Added it. All slides (.slide1, .slide2, so on) are to the left of the visible body by default.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give it a shot, does this help you with portability?

```
$(".openslide1").click(function() {
      openSlide(".slide1", "body", 400, ".openslide1");
});

function openSlide(target, bodyObj, speed, original) {
      $(target).animate({
        left: "+=250px",
      }, speed, function() {
        // Animation complete.
      });
      $(bodyObj).animate({
        marginLeft: "+=250px",
      }, speed, function() {
        // Animation complete.
      });
      $(original).unbind('click');
}
```

Comment: Not quite working for me. It moves the body over...but doesn't seem to move the slide1, or unbind the openslide1.

Comment: Damn. I made some quick changes. I'll have another look in a second

Answer (score 0):

Change you function to pass a reference to the element (or elements) that you want to manipulate:

```
var openslide = function(elem) { 
  var id = elem.attr("id");
  $("#" + id.substring(5)).animate({
    left: "+=250px",
  }, 400, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
  $('body').animate({
    marginLeft: "+=250px",
  }, 400, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
  elem.unbind('click', openslide);
};

$(".edit-btn").click(function() {openslide($(this))});
```

Then you can use a single function for all your elements and you can bind them all at the same time if they have a common class (in this case, I called them `.openslide`).

Edit: looking at your original question again, I noticed that the element being animated at the start isn't the same element. But if there is an easily defined relationship between it and the element you clicked on (for example, it's a child of the original element, or the next sibling, or something) you can easily come up with the appropriate selector to select it. In the example above, I assumed a sibling relationship with the target element having a class of `.targetclass`, but change it as suits.

Edit 2: changed it to use the id's on the assumption that id `openslide1` will correspond to the element with id `slide1`.

Comment: Unfortunately they won't really be in any sort of next sibling situation. Forgive my limited knowledge of jQuery here. I updated my original question with some HTML that might help show what I'm meaning. I used classes in the case of the slides themselves, even though they maybe should have been id's. The .openslide link will correspond to it's unique slide.

Comment: @HarlanBowling: yes, you'd be better off using id's. Then you can do simple string manipulation to get from an id of `openslide1` to the id of `slide1` that you want to manipulate. You *could* probably do the same thing with the classes, but since you have two classes on each element, it'll be slightly trickier.

Comment: Ok...that's perfectly fine. Can you help me with the script on it, assuming I change the openslide1, openslide2, etc classes to ID's...and the slide1, slide2, etc. classes to ID's?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working. Doesn't seem to be moving the body or slide over. I have changed the edit link to be an id of "openslide1" and the corresponding slide to an id of "slide1"...but no dice.

Comment: Made edits to my OP to show where I'm at now. Hopefully it clears some things up too.

Answer (score 0):

Construct the links as follows :

```
<div class="section">
    <a class="edit-btn openslide" data-slide="#slide1" href="#null">edit</a>
    <a class="edit-btn openslide" data-slide="#slide2" href="#null">edit</a>
    <a class="edit-btn openslide" data-slide="#slide3" href="#null">edit</a>
    <a class="edit-btn openslide" data-slide="#slide4" href="#null">edit</a>
</div>
```

And the slides as follows :

```
<div class="slide" id="slide1">
<h1>Edit Row</h1>
<p>Prototyping data below, may not reflect link clicked.</p>
<a href="#null" class="submitslide1 btn btn-primary">Submit</a> <a class="closeslide1 btn btn-danger" style="color:#fff" href="#null">Cancel</a>
</div>
```

It's hard to see exactly what effect is required but the general shape of the handler will be something like this :

```
$(".openslide, .closeslide").click(function() {
    if($("body").filter(":animated").length) { return; } //animation in progress, abort.
    var $slide = $($(this).data('slide'));
    var state = $slide.data('state') || 'closed';
    var sign = (state == 'closed') ? '+' : '-';
    $slide.animate({
        left: sign + "=250px"
    }, 400, function(){
        $slide.data('state', (sign == '+') ? 'open' : 'closed');
    });
    $('body').animate({
        marginLeft: sign + "=250px"
    }, 400);
    return false;
});
```

*untested*

As you will see, one function (when it works) will handle both slideopen and slideclose actions.

You will have to adapt the script to achieve precisely what you want.